# Help with logarithms?

Tags: logarithms

Find the value of $x$ in:

$5.25 = -\log_{10} (x)$

What should I do with a negative log?

Should i do $5.25= \frac{1}{\log_{10}(x)}$ ?

Comment: $-\log x=\log\dfrac1x\neq\dfrac1{\log x}$

Comment: -5.25=log10(x). Then x=10^(-5.25).

Comment: so is $5.25=log{1\over {x}}$ equal to $-5.25=log(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms to the base $a$ mean: $y = a^x \iff x = \log_a(y)$

Therefore, $5.25 = -\log_{10}(x) \iff -5.25 = \log_{10}(x) \iff 10^{-5.25} = x$.
You can use Wolfram or calculator to get approximate value $= 5.6234 \times 10^{-6}$.